# Conditional Data fetching using SWR in react and calling axios inside array map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, swr

I have two different API end points to fetch data from. The second endpoint requires a query parameter that comes from the first endpoints response.

I am using useSWR hook with axios inside a custom hook which looks like-

```
import axios from '@/lib/axios'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import useSWR from 'swr'

export const useSubjects = ({ id, path } = {}) => {
    /**
     * Fetcher Function for SWR
     */
    const fetchSubjects = async url => {
        return await axios
            .get(url)
            .then(res => res.data)
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status !== 409) throw error
            })
    }

    const fetchThumbnail = async (url, path) => {
        var thumbImages = []
        await path.map(async pathdata => {
            // console.log(url + pathdata)
            await axios
                .get(url + pathdata, {
                    responseType: 'blob',
                })
                .then(res => thumbImages.push(res.data))
                .catch(error => {
                    throw error
                })
        })

        return thumbImages
    }

    /**
     * swr hook for fetching subjects
     */
    const {
        data: subjects,
        error: SubjectError,
        mutate: mutateSubject,
    } = useSWR(
        id > 0 ? `api/get-subject-branch/${id}` : 'api/get-subject-branches',
        fetchSubjects,
    )

    /* swr hook for fetching thumbnails */
    const {
        data: thumbnail,
        error: thumbnailError,
        mutate: mutateThumbnail,
    } = useSWR(
        path ? ['api/get-subject-thumbnail?thumbnail_url=', path] : null,
        fetchThumbnail,
    )

    return {
        subjects,
        thumbnail,
        mutateSubject,
        mutateThumbnail,
    }
}
```

Using the hook:

```
const AdminCourses = () => {
    const [thumbnailPaths, setThumbnailPaths] = useState([])
    const [thumbBlob, setThumbBlob] = useState([])
    // const [thumbnail, setThumbnail] = useState()

    // Subjects fetched from API using subjects hook

    const { subjects, thumbnail, mutateSubject, mutateThumbnail } = useSubjects(
        {
            path: thumbnailPaths,
        },
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        if (subjects) {
            setThumbnailPaths([])
            subjects?.data?.map(sub => {
                setThumbnailPaths(thumbnailPaths => [
                    ...thumbnailPaths,
                    sub.thumbnail_url,
                ])
            })
        }
    }, [subjects])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (thumbnail) {
            setThumbBlob([])

            thumbnail?.map(thumbnailBlobData => {
                console.log(thumbnailBlobData)

                var imgData = []
                imgData.push(thumbnailBlobData)

                setThumbBlob(thumbBlob => [
                    ...thumbBlob,
                    URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(imgData, { type: 'Image/*' })),
                ])
            })
        }
        // console.log('calling effect to update data')

        return () => {
            thumbBlob.map(data => URL.revokeObjectURL(data))
        }
    }, [subjects, thumbnail])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (thumbnailPaths?.length != 0) {
            console.log("calling thumbnail swr", thumbnailPaths, thumbBlob);
            mutateThumbnail()
        }
    }, [thumbnailPaths])

return (<>
        {subjects?.data?.map((data, ind) => (
                    <div key={'subject' + ind}>
                        <hr className="bg-black h-101 mt-8" />
                        {/* Start of Subjects / Courses */}
                        <div className="flex justify-between items-center lg:flex-col md:flex-row sm:flex-col my-4">
                            {/* subject thumbnail */}
                            <div className="w-32 pl-8 lg:mt-8 md:mt-0 sm:mt-8">
                                <Image
                                    src={
                                        thumbBlob?.length != 0
                                            ? thumbBlob[ind]
                                            : '/image/blog-2.jpg'
                                    }
                                    width={5706}
                                    height={3840}
                                    layout="responsive"
                                    objectFit="cover"
                                    className="rounded-xl"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex flex-col lg:mt-8 md:mt-0 sm:mt-8">
                                {/* subject title */}
                                {/* <h1 className="text-xl font-bold">
                                    {data.subject_name}
                                </h1> */}
                                <CourseNav
                                    DataName={data.subject_name}
                                    className="relative -left-6 bg-btn-color font-bold rounded-md shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none"
                                />
                            </div>
                            {/* subject description */}
                            <h4 className="text-sm font-bold self-center w-2/5 lg:text-base lg:w-3/4 lg:mt-8 md:mt-0 md:w-2/5 md:text-sm sm:text-base sm:w-3/4 sm:mt-8">
                                {data.subject_description}
                            </h4>
                            <div className="flex justify-between items-center lg:my-8 md:my-0 sm:my-8">
                                {/* Edit Button */}
                                <div className="cursor-pointer hover:scale-110 transform transition-all duration-500 pr-8">
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPen} size="2x" />
                                </div>

                                {/* delete video btn */}
                                <div className="cursor-pointer hover:scale-110 transform transition-all duration-500">
                                    <DeleteIcon />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {/* End of Subjects / Courses */}
                    </div>
                ))}
</>
    )}
```

The given custom hook in the first snippet is used in the component given in the second snippet.

The Data:

There are two types of data fetched using these end points

First, an array of json objects containing `subjects`

Second, array of blob of images - `thumbnail`

The `subjects` array contains `thumbnail_url` in each element.
The images are fetched using those `thumbnail_url`

The Problem:

The thumbnail_url paths are stored in the state hook `thumbnailPaths` which is an array of all thumbnail_urls
Again, `thumbnailPaths` is passed as an object parameter in useSubjects hook.

Initial call to useSubjects hook is definitely an empty array of `thumbnailPaths`. But later when the `thumbnailPaths` array is populated with data it is expected to call the `useSubjects` hook with the updated `thumbnailPaths` array.

Shouldn't it re-render the component and call useSubjects again so that the second useSWR in useSubject custom hook gets called again?

What is happening in this case is. Despite `thumbnailPaths` being populated the second useSWR hook is not being called unless `mutateSubject()` is being called which I am calling using a button click.

The call to `mutateThumbnail` seems to have no effect whatsoever.

I am getting thumbnail images only on calling `mutateSubjects`

What I want is to get "All" data in one go without having to reload or press any button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't await for an array like that:

```
        await path.map(async pathdata => {
            // console.log(url + pathdata)
            await axios
                .get(url + pathdata, {
                    responseType: 'blob',
                })
                .then(res => thumbImages.push(res.data))
                .catch(error => {
                    throw error
                })
        })
```

Array is not a Promise-like so all this stuff inside `fetchThumbnail` resolves immediately with an empty array. You need to you use `Promise.all` if you want to wait for an array of promises.